# I want to integrate the payment gateway of paytm in a small modal iframe in my project

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm in a planning phase so i just wanted to see if all the thing that I was thinking can be achieved or not it's just theoretical question and just want your advice on it

The thing that I want is that a person should click on a link and a small modal  on right side should pop up as shown in the below image
[image]

Once that is done now i want it to have the payment gateway appear only inside that modal and not in the full view
I'm going to start building this project for learning so any help or guidance will be great
If possible please add the references as well on how this can be achieved

Comment: Yes, you can do that using something called "Inline Checkout" Payment option (Usually a lot of Payment Gateways offer this option) and provide you with a `callback` function so you can do a specific behavior on payment success for example.

Comment: This option allows you to embed the Payment Gateway on a specific element that you give it the proper/required ID for example, so the payment gateway can embed its stuff inside that specific element only. Please note that you won't be able to edit/modify the inline-checkout style itself (The font color of all card info for example) using your own CSS, it must be done via the Payment Gateway (some of them provide you with simple customization like General Theme Color to be applied on Call-to-actions)... Hope that helps, and best of luck on your project, Sachin!!

Answer (score 0):

Please use our JS checkout solution for this, it would work. You need to create your own modal.
In JS checkout configuration you need to pass the modal div id